# How to redirect to the same page after login in jsp?

Tags: jsp, jsf

I am a beginner in jsp web development. I have a requirement that in the Login page, the user is shown different form fields based on a drop down selection.Once selected, on click of the login, he must be redirected to the same page with a session created and a logout option. Not sure how to implement all these requirements.

How can i implement the dynamic fields onchange of dropdown and create a session on login within the same page?

Note: i am using JSF 1.2 in the project.

The jquery used to realize the dropdown and login:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("div","div#logout").hide();

 $("div","div#fields").hide();
    $("#dropdown").change(function(){

       $("div","div#fields").hide();
       var value=    $("#dropdown").val();
    $("div#"+value).show();
});

});

$(login1).click(function(){
 $("div","div#fields").hide();
    $("div#logout").show();

 });
```

When i click on the login, the page submits calling the ready function again. Is there any other way of implementing this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just do the following:

- check for the parameters that are submitted to the servlet
- create your session accordingly
- Dispatch to your original page
- check for session you just created
- Disable/enable controls on the page

This is how you do it by maintaining a session in your application

```
//page submission at your server
HttpSession session = request.getSession();

//set your session variable here
session.setAttribute("validUser", someValue);

//redirect your page back to login page
response.sendRedirect(URL);
```

Back at your login homepage, check for session variable in JQuery and display accordingly:

```
// Read your session variable here
//you can set a boolean to check if the user is logged in then do not call the routine or otherwise
$(function() {
 alert( $.session("validUser") );
});
```

Comment: i had tried implementing jquery for the form fields change. But when i click on login, the page submits and the fields get hidden. This is the jquery i have used:

Comment: use the controls properly, add an edit to you original post and paste your code there.

Comment: i had tried implementing jquery for the form fields change. But when i click on login, the page submits and the fields get hidden giving error saying the fields are empty. Can you please suggest some solution using Jquery.

Comment: can you provide us with the code or show us what you are upto, only then we will be able to help.

Comment: i have edited my post and added the jquery used.For the dropdown to display different fields onchange i have created a div tag and based on the value change the jquery will display the associated div tag fields. Now when i login, i want to create a session and display the logout option in place. But with the above code the page refreshes the fields get hidden without the login getting triggered.

Comment: I have made an edit to my answer